# Powermock: java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, powermock, easymock

I am upgrading my codebase to JDK11. I recently moved to:

Mockito version - 2.23.4

Powermock version - 2.0.2

I used [this](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito#supported-versions) link to verify that both above versions are compatible.
Now I have been running into many weird issues. One of them is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invoking the beforeTestMethod method on PowerMock test listener org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler@291953c5 failed.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.powermock.api.easymock.internal.invocationcontrol.EasyMockMethodInvocationControl cannot be cast to class org.powermock.api.mockito.invocation.MockitoMethodInvocationControl (org.powermock.api.easymock.internal.invocationcontrol.EasyMockMethodInvocationControl is in unnamed module of loader org.powermock.core.classloader.javassist.JavassistMockClassLoader @3ac3f6f; org.powermock.api.mockito.invocation.MockitoMethodInvocationControl is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I'm not doing anything fancy here and nothing has changed from when I was using older Powermock versions with JDK8 where everything worked fine.

My `@Before` method is something like:

```
private Xyz mockXyz = PowerMock.createMock(Xyz.class);   //Xyz is a final class 
private XyzClient mockXyzClient = PowerMock.createMock(XyzClient.class);

@Before
public void beforeTest() {
    expect(mockXyzClient.api()).andReturn(mockXyz).anyTimes();
}
```

Not sure if it helps but my test classes have:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.crypto.*", "javax.net.ssl.*", 
"javax.management.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", 
"javax.xml.parsers.*", "org.xml.*", "org.w3c.dom.*" })
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else faces this. I was able to work around this.

All I had to do was move the `PowerMock.createMock()` call to my @Before annotated method. So I had to do something like:

```
private Xyz mockXyz;   //Xyz is a final class 
private XyzClient mockXyzClient;

@Before
public void beforeTest() {
    mockXyz = PowerMock.createMock(Xyz.class); 
    mockXyzClient = PowerMock.createMock(XyzClient.class);
    expect(mockXyzClient.api()).andReturn(mockXyz).anyTimes();
}
```